# i18nFormat with CakePHP 3 - Why does YYYY produce a different year than yyyy?

Tags: php, time, internationalization, cakephp-3.0

I'm working in CakePHP 3 and I noticed today that this:

```
    $time = new Time('now');

    $this->set('time', $time->i18nFormat('YYYY')); // echoes '2015'
```

Echoes 2015. Changing it to lowercase 'yyyy', instead, produces 2014.

```
    $time = new Time('now');

    $this->set('time', $time->i18nFormat('yyyy')); // echoes '2014'
```

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uppercase `Y` is the year that the week of the timestamp is in "*Week of Year*" based calendars.  This week `now`, is in 2015 so it returns 2015.  Lowercase `y` is the current year for the timestamp, which for `now` is 2014.

[Date Field Symbol Table](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table)